# Java how to create a custom Exception to limit the size of a HashMap

Tags: java, exception

I have a method which inserts new items to a `HashMap`, I want to limit the size of the `HashMap` by throw an `exception` when the size of the HashMap is larger than a specific value, say `100`, below is my implementation:

```
public void addToHashMap(String id, Object value) throws HashMapOutOfBoundException{
    hashMap.put(id,value);    
}

private class HashMapOutOfBoundException extends Exception{
    //what should I do inside this class?
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not a simple:

```
public void addToHashMap(String id, Object value) {
    if (hashMap.size()+1 > MAX_SIZE)
      throw new HashMapOutOfBoundException();
    hashMap.put(id,value);    
}
```

with

```
public class HashMapOutOfBoundException extends RuntimeException {}
```

From the javadoc:

> RuntimeException and its subclasses are unchecked exceptions.
>   Unchecked exceptions do not need to be declared in a method or
>   constructor's throws clause if they can be thrown by the execution of
>   the method or constructor and propagate outside the method or
>   constructor boundary.

Comment: So inside the HashMapOutOfBoundException class I do nothing? I want to limit the size of the HashMap inside HashMapOutOfBoundException class.

Comment: If using RuntimeException, I don't need to create HashMapOutOfBoundException class but just throw new RuntimeException, right?

Comment: @user3491420 You could use a base RuntimeException, but it isn't advisable. How are you going to handle a specific exception case if the exception thrown is not specific? 
@Nizil the condition in your if statement suggests that the size limit has already been breached, I'd go with `(hashMap.size() + 1) > MAX_SIZE`

Comment: @user3491420 Right ! But the error stacktrace will be less understandable, and the exception will be less 'catchable' :) I don't understand what you means by "limit the size of the HashMap inside HashMapOutOfBoundException"